# JQuery-mobile : Load JQPlot graph through AJAX request

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, jqplot

I am new on JQuery Mobile and I am trying to display a page with a JqPlot graphic depending on the user choice.

I read and experimented this morning that by design the javascript code of a page displayed/loaded by clicking on a link is not executed.

To taking into account JS script of a page to load, the data attribute `data-ajax` of the link must be set to false. But in this case, the browser reload all the page and the is no smooth transition for the user.

```
<p><a href="myUrl.php" data-ajax= "false" data-transition="slideup" data-role="button" data-theme="c">
```

I have found a way to figure it out, **but I need an expert review of my code**. The idea is to declare an event `pageshow` on the graph container page `#page-detail` to load the graph creation page through the JQuery `.load()` function.

By this way, I am able to :

- Have a smooth transition to my page
- Have a loading div where my graph will be loaded
- Render my graph when the data loading and JqPlot graph is ready

My code :

```
  $(document).on('pageshow','#page-detail',function(){       
        //Apply a loading layer to the graph container
        $('#graph-container').html("<div id='graph-loading-layer' class='loading loading-col2a'>"+g_graphLoadingText+"</div>");                    

        //Load my graphic page creation. In this page, there are JS code to create the JQplot graphic
        $('#graph-container').load(g_baseUrl+"index/graph/format/html",{chartHeight : newHeight+'px'},function(response, status, xhr) {
            console.log('loaded')
        });                 
    });
```

My solution above is painful an I am sure that I could load my graph easily 
Is there someone with a better solution? Better code implementation?

Answer (score 0):

JQuery `.load()` is a good option for loading pages including having the Javascript executed and CSS applied as per a standard page load. I used this technique with partial pages in an MVC single-page website and found it to be very effective.

I wasn't entirely clear on your concerns around the links, but certainly using JQuery .load() within a 'click' handler for links will also work.

Your code looks sound, and it's good to see that you are applying a loading layer while the async load happens. I'm not sure 100% sure how that layer works for you, but I'm thinking you probably need to hide/remove it once the `.load()` has completed, so perhaps there needs to be some extra code in your post-load handler to do so?

Comment: Yeah, you are right. But my question is more about `.load()` utilisation in JQuery Mobile context. My solution above is painful an I am sure that I could load my graph easily

Comment: What in particular is 'painful' for you with this option, and what alternatives have you explored?

Comment: Thanks for updatding your answer. Actually, the loading layer is overwritten by the graph code when the page has been load.

Comment: In my point of view, it is not convenient to use this method every times I need to execute JS code written in the page to load. I know that it is for mobiles and JS code must be loaded only the first time to be efficient, but sometimes, the page must execute particular JS code and it is more convenient to write the in the page itself.