# Links not working from AJAX slider when in JQuery Mobile Page?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I've been working away on a small jquery mobile app. I got a slider to pull slides from a remote XML and pop them into the carousel fine. In a normal blank page this works fine and on click the browser goes to the appropriate page.

When the exact same code is inserted into a mobile page - the links do not open up. Tried data-ajax false, but no luck. I'm wondering if it's .live() but I'm not sure where I would place this? Any help would be appreciated.

```
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "http://www.xxxxxx.com/file.xml
            dataType: "xml",
            success: function(xml) {
                $(xml).find('coupon').each(function(){
                    var url = $(this).find('link').text();
                    var imageurl = $(this).find('imageurl').text();

                    $('<li></li>').html('<a href="' + url + '" data-ajax="false"> <img src="' + imageurl + '" data-ajax="false"/></a>').appendTo('#es-carousel-deals');

                });

                $('#deals').elastislide({
                    imageW  : 128,
                    minItems    : 5
                });


            }
        });

    });
```

Comment: Syntax error, you missed to close string and the coma in the url parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an exemple to use .on() function to load dynamic data in your mobile application :

[JQuery-mobile : Load JQPlot graph through AJAX request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13761878/jquery-mobile-load-jqplot-graph-through-ajax-request)

Comment: Sorted this one:

rel="external" is all that it needed. :) Thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

rel="external"

Sorted this one.