# Show jqplot in jquery page

Tags: jquery, cordova, jqplot

I'm doing an app using Phonegap (Cordova) and I'm using jquery mobile for that. I have created a dynamic jqplot with some database and the problem is this: The plot isn't shown at my page, but it appear if I reload the page (with F5 in Chrome) But I wanted to reload it automatically or another solution in order to see the plot. (I've tried with window.location.reload but it redirect me to the first page and my plot is in other one) Thanks!

```
<script class="code" type="text/javascript">
var dia = 2;
var plot2;
var line1=[[]];
var ultimopeso;
var dia_registro_global=0;
// PhoneGap code 
x$(document).on("deviceready", function () {

}); 

var listElement = x$('#devuelvepeso');
var messageElement = x$('#devuelvefecha');
var db;

x$('#saveItems').on('click', function(e) {
    insertItem();
});

// Create a reference to the database
function getDatabase() {
return window.openDatabase("Seguimiento","1.0", "Seguimiento Database", 200000);
}


onDeviceReady();
// PhoneGap is ready
function onDeviceReady() {
        db = getDatabase();
        db.transaction(function(tx) {
        tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS SEGUIMIENTO(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, reportPeso)');
}, databaseError, getItems);
}




// Insert a record into the database
function insertItem() {
var insertValue = document.getElementById('reportPeso').value;
db.transaction(function(tx) {tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO SEGUIMIENTO(reportPeso) VALUES ("' + insertValue + '")');
}, databaseError, getItems);

}

// Database error handler
function databaseError(error) {
messageElement.html("SQL Error: " + error.code);
}

// consulta bbdd
function getItems() {
    db.transaction(function(tx){
    tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM SEGUIMIENTO', [], querySuccess, databaseError);
}, databaseError);

}


function querySuccess(tx, result) {

    for (var i = 0; i < result.rows.length; i++) {
        var row = result.rows.item(i);
        line1.push([row.id, parseInt(row.reportPeso)]); 
        ultimopeso = row.reportPeso;
    }
}
$(window).load(function(){

reset_dia();
var len;

plot2 = $.jqplot ('chart1', [line1], {
  title: 'Seguimiento del peso',
  axesDefaults: {
    labelRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisLabelRenderer
  },
  axes: {
    xaxis: {
      label: "Semana",
      pad: 0
    },
    yaxis: {
      label: "Peso"
    }
  }

});
})
```

[Here there are another 'div data-role="page"']

```
<div data-role="page" id="seguimiento"  >
<div data-role="navbar"  >
        <ul>
    <li><a href="#midieta"><img src="images/menu/lista_dietas_logo-01-01.png"></a></li>
    <li><a href="#lista" ><img src="images/menu/mi_dieta_logo-01.png"></a></li>
    <li><a href="#perfil" onClick="cargar_datos_perfil();"><img src="images/menu/perfil_logo-01.png"></a></li>
    <li><a href="#pro"><img src="images/menu/lista_dietas_logo-01-01.png"></a></li>
    <li><a href="#seguimiento"  class="ui-btn-active ui-state-persist" onClick="recargagrafico()"><img src="images/menu/seguimiento_logo-01.png"></a></li>
    <li><a href="#preguntas"><img src="images/menu/preguntas_logo-01.png"></a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div data-role="header"  >
 <h1>Seguimiento</h1>
</div>
<div data-role="content"  >



<div id="chart1" style="height:50%; width:100%;">

</div>
<!--<pre class="code prettyprint brush: js"></pre>-->
</div>
<div data-role="footer"  >
   <h4>x</h4>
   </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Have a look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13761878/jquery-mobile-load-jqplot-graph-through-ajax-request

Answer (score 0):

I finally get the solution! Using .live() when the page is shown I create my plot. Thank you!

```
$('#seguimiento').live('pageshow', function() {

   plot2 = $.jqplot ('chart1', [line1], {
     title: 'Seguimiento del peso',
     axesDefaults: {
      labelRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisLabelRenderer
  },
  axes: {
    xaxis: {
      label: "Semana",
      pad: 0
    },
    yaxis: {
      label: "Peso"
    }
  }

});
```

});

Answer (score 0):

For my case, I use

```
$(document).on('pageshow','#seguimiento',function(){
```

able to display jqplot, I use:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="plugins/jqplot.highlighter.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="plugins/jqplot.cursor.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="plugins/jqplot.dateAxisRenderer.min.js"></script>
```

in my phonegap project.